# Create the "Blockchain" tag for the "Industries" select option

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

The blockchain industry has attracted more and more attention from the modern community. However, we can't find similar keywords from the *Industries* select option which is in the *Match* preferences of the *Job preferences* page.

[image]

---

Both the *Industries* and *Industries to exclude* sections should add this tag.

[image]

Comment: Is blockchain an industry on its own?

Comment: It certainly seems like a more useful job criterion than "food and beverages" or "beauty"

Comment: ...but blockchain isn't an industry.  It's a(n often misunderstood and misapplied) technology.  You can't buy or sell blockchain, and you don't do business *in* blockchain, either.  You can build smart ledgers (which may be more towards Finance), and you can buy and sell crypto (which is just...crypto), but *none* of this makes blockchain an industry.

Comment: @Makoto - ```ou can't buy or sell blockchain, and you don't do business in blockchain, either. ``` actually, thanks to the buzzwordieness of it, you pretty much can. https://www.theverge.com/2017/12/21/16805598/companies-blockchain-tech-cryptocurrency-tea :-D

Comment: @JeremyBanks Both of these examples are bona fide industries (both of which extensively rely on IT to run their business!). “Blockchain” isn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Blockchain isn't, but I question the utility of "industry" as a top level category at all. I doubt many people are going to be searching on these sites for jobs by vague broad industry categories.

Comment: @JeremyBanks All I can say that for myself and others I know, the industry is *more important* than the technologies. Case in point, few technologies would be a complete deal-breaker, but industries definitely are.

Comment: I came here hoping to see if we could get "Crypto-Currency" added as an industry. You *can* buy and sell cryptocurrencies. And I'm perfectly happy to work in any other part of the "Finance" industry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two important fields:

- Technology
- Industry

Blockchain is a technology and you can find it in the relevant field:

[image]

Note that you can find "Finance" among Industries.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. This is actually way better.